# Ember.computed.sort property not updating

Tags: ember.js

I've been cracking my head for the last several days, trying to understand what am I doing wrong.
I'm implementing an infrastructure of lists for my app, which can include `paging/infinite scroll/filtering/grouping/`etc. The implementation is based on extending controllers (not array controllers, I want to be Ember 2.0 safe), with a `content` array property that holds the data.

I'm using Ember.computed.sort for the sorting, and it's working, but i have a strange behavior when i try to change the sorter. the `sortedContent` is not updating within the `displayContent`, even though the `sortingDefinitions` definitions are updated.

This causes a weird behaviour that it will only sort if I `sort` it twice, as if the sorting was asynchronous.

I am using `Ember 1.5` (but it also happens on 1.8) 
(attaching a snippet of code explaining my problem)

```
sortingDefinitions: function(){
    var sortBy = this.get('sortBy');
    var sortOrder = this.get('sortOrder') || 'asc';

    if (_.isArray(sortBy)) {
        return sortBy;
    }
    else {
        return (sortBy ? [sortBy + ':' + sortOrder] : []);
    }
}.property('sortBy', 'sortOrder'),

sortedContent: Ember.computed.sort('content', 'sortingDefinitions'),




displayContent: function() {
    var that = this;
    var sortBy = this.get('sortBy');
    var sortOrder = this.get('sortOrder');
    var list = (sortBy ? this.get('sortedContent') : this.get('content'));

    var itemsPerPage = this.get('itemsPerPage');
    var currentPage = this.get('currentPage');
    var listItemModel = this.get('listItemModel');

    return list.filter(function(item, index, enumerable){
        return ((index >= (currentPage * itemsPerPage)) && (index < ((currentPage + 1)  * itemsPerPage)));
    }).map(function(item) {
        var listItemModel = that.get('listItemModel');
        if (listItemModel) {
            return listItemModel.create(item);
        }
        else {
            return item;
        }
    });

}.property('content.length', 'sortBy', 'sortOrder', 'currentPage', 'itemsPerPage')
```

**Edit:**
fixed by adding another dependency to the displayContent (sortedContent.[]):

```
displayContent: function() {
    ....

}.property('content.length', 'sortBy', 'sortOrder', 'currentPage', 'itemsPerPage' , 'sortedContent.[]')
```

Comment: note that it works fine on my unit-tests. something with the rendering loop is messed up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sort function is watching the whole array `sortingDefinitions` instead of each element in the array. If the array changed to a string or some other variable it would update but not if an element in the array changes.

To ensure your computed property updates correctly, add a `.[]` to the end of the array so it looks like this: `Ember.computed.sort('content', 'sortingDefinitions.[]')`

Comment: but the entire array is being replaced. the real weird part is that when sort twice it works. (tried your solution anyway, didn't work) :(

Comment: ok, I found the issue, and it's not that different.
adding 'sortedContent.[]' to the displayContent properties list did the trick. my bad.